# UWP Real time audio on windows 10

Tags: c#, directx, uwp, wasapi

I would like to ask you: In my company I should develop the communication app. Something like Skype etc. We have our custom SIP implementation. Data are encrypted by RSA, or something like that. Now, I'm looking for some solution, how to implement capturing audio on windows 10 (desktop, phone)
I found something about WASAPI, XAudio2. I think, the best option is WASAPI. But It will be working on Windows 10 Mobile? Or would you recommend me any third part libraries like SharpDX, NAudio? I need echo cancellation, and Im not sure, if WASAPI supports echo cancellation.
All advices will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WASAPI is definitely available on windows mobile 10.

but you could capture the audio directly with the "voice capture dsp"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff819492(v=VS.85).aspx

i found no info about its availability on win mobile 10, but it's really probable you can use it there too.

Comment: Also Xaudio2 is available on win10 mobile, but is probably not what you want since you need echo cancellation